VSCode(1.90.0) crashes when starting up in Ubuntu 22.04
Vscode was actively working on my ubuntu machine. Suddenly after a system restart the vscode started crashing on startup.
vscode version:
vscode version:
code verbose:
I tried uninstalling & re installing the VScode from snapstore but this wont work.

Does this answer your question? Visual Studio Code crashes on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

I found the solution by uninstalling the VScode from Snapstore. Then download the .deb vscode package from the official site and install it. The problem might be mixing the .snap package installation with the .deb package.

A temporary solution is to revert the VSCode to its previous version until the support team fixes it. Try to run this from your terminal:
sudo snap revert code


Can confirm that this worked for me. Will this update the code when a new version comes out or does this stall upgrading forever?

Found it: A snap won’t automatically update to a version previously reverted from, and the output from snap refresh will continue to state All snaps up to date. A reverted snap will be automatically updated when a new and different revision is made available by the publisher.

first uninstall vs code from you machine

snap remove code

then update

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Restart your machine and run following commands

sudo apt-get install wget gpg
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main" |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list > /dev/null
rm -f packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code


I have issue too. My VScode was working fine yesterday(6-6-2024). But I think snap is automatically updated my vscode. Then when I open VSC, it's immediately close.
My solution is uninstall from snap store. Delete .vscode folder and ~/.config/Code folder. Then I downloaded deb package from official website and installed it. THEN BOOM! It's working now.

Uninstall it from snap and install it with dpkg:
sudo dpkg -i code_1.90.0-1717531825_amd64.deb


Seems like the problem is only with Snap version.
Installing latest version from .deb package works just fine.
Some workarounds I've found so far:

Install .deb package from official
source
Run code --in-process-gpu on terminal
Run code --use-gl=angle --use-angle=swiftshader
Revert to older snap version with sudo snap revert code --revision 159

They will probably fix it soon, but, for now, that's the solution I found

i did notice that when i run
while true; do sudo ps aux | grep -i vscode | grep -v grep; done

and then attempt to launch vscode normally, this gets the path of the vscode instance.
mine ends up like this.
/snap/code/160/usr/share/code/code

when i run it from the command line without the extra arguments it does run properly.  This may be a no external dependency work around until it is fixed in the snap store.
